# Add slashes and redirect pages with htacess and apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, expressionengine

Im trying to make it so everything with news.php in the url gets redirected to a url which strips out the news.php and adds a trailing slash.  So http://www.example.com/news.php/news/article to http://www.example.com/news/article/

Ive been able to remove the news.php with this

```
RewriteRule  ^(news|health|tips|weight|P[0-9]{2,8})$ $1/ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 ^((news|health|tips|weight|P[0-9]{2,8})/) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /news.php/$1 [L]
```

Ive tried adding a trailing slash to the above line and it does nothing.
I have also tried the stuff below, which adds a slash but doesnt remove the news.php.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /news.php/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Can someone help me out here Im not sure what to do?

I also have some other rules

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f  

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(ACT=.*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(URL=.*)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(CSS=.*)$ [NC]   
RewriteRule ^$ /news.php\?&%{QUERY_STRING} [L] 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]     
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www2\. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www2.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an additional rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /news\.php/\S+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^news\.php/(.+?)/?$ /$1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 ^((news|health|tips|weight|P[0-9]{2,8})/) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /news.php/$1 [L]
```

**EDIT:** To add a trailing slash to all non-files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This is not adding a trailing slash to the URL for me.

Comment: For some reason the first RewriteRule is never happening for me.

Comment: Using this exact rule `/news.php/news/article` became `/news/news/article/` in my browser. Do you have other rules also in your .htaccess?

Comment: I was trying to change /news.php/news/article to /news/article/   I have other rules also one minute.

Comment: Oh not in comment, post them in question by editing it.

Comment: This line `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+news\.php/(\S+) [NC]`  I dont think is working for me properly because no matter what I put as the rewrite rule after it stays the same.

Comment: This is a working rule and fully tested one. Make sure this 301 rule is very first rule just below `RewriteEngine On`. Also what is location of your .htaccess?

Comment: Yes, I have rewrite engine on.  It is also the first thing after.  My htaccess is in my root folder.  I copy and pasted your code into my htaccess and removed everthing else and I still dont get a trailing slash.

Comment: So `/news.php/news/article` remains unchanged? Also I asked you location of .htaccess?

Comment: Im running apache 2.2.  Maybe we have different versions?

Comment: No /news.php/news/article is /news/article So its getting rid of news.php just no trailing slash.  My htaccess is in the root directory of my site.

Comment: I still don't get a trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I changed the first block anubhava suggested to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

and now everything seems to be working as I want.

Comment: As per question you needed trailing slash for `/news.php` link

Comment: That's true, that is what I'm trying to do.  But I couldn't get that to work so this just seems to add a trailing slash to anything that doesn't have an extension.  Thanks for helping me.

Comment: see **EDIT** in my answer for slightly better way to add trailing slash in every URI